# How to connect two locally linked computers to WIFI using IPv4 addressing?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, wifi-configuration, ipv4

1. I want to connect my **laptop** and **another computer** (which is RaspberryPi 2, but that's not very important) using a **crossover** cable.
2. Then I would like to **SSH** from my laptop to another computer.
3. Finally, I want to connect my laptop to **WIFI** and make sure that through SSH'd terminal I will also be able to use WIFI on another computer.

Now I managed to complete parts (1) and (2). With the absence of WIFI the RaspberryPi gets a **unique same IP address 169.254.114.180** even if I reboot both machines. (?That's called the link-local address assignment if I'm not mistaken?). I can then use this IP address to SSH into it.

The problem is that shortly after my Laptop connects to WIFI, Pi gets assigned **new** IP address (?Is that due to DHCP?) and the SSH connection is **lost**. That's the place where I get stuck, because I don't know how to detect the change of address, or to make link-local address permanent.

**Could someone help me to solve part (3)?**

You should assume that I have **no router**, also, my RaspberryPi device is **not connected** to external mouse, keyboard or screen. So far the only way to operate and monitor the Pi is through SSH using the **crossover cable without external internet** (I don't want to take SD card away from device and work just with it). From my laptop I can work on both Ubuntu or Windows OS'es.

Comment: If you are connecting the laptop and Rasberry Pi by a crossover cable, why don't you use [static IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Static_IP) on both sides of the wired connection? You can use [private IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) for the Ethernet connections on both sides. E.g., one system could have an IP address of 192.168.3.1 and the other 192.168.3.2 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.248 for both. You can then establish an SSH connection to the one functioning as an SSH server using the static IP address for the SSH server.

Comment: Ok, this comment solves the problem of making IP address permanent (thx for that), but it does not solve the second problem: how to connect to WIFI.

From your link: **However, IP packets addressed from them cannot be transmitted through the public Internet, and so if such a private network needs to connect to the Internet, it must do so via a network address translator (NAT) gateway, or a proxy server.**

I need more detail how to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to:

- 1) Connect RaspberryPi with laptop using crossover cable.
- 2) SSH into RaspberryPi and get virtual terminal on my Laptop.
- 3) Have Wifi on the virtual terminal.
- 4) Have Wifi on my PC, Linux OS.

Here are instructions that worked for me:

From PC go to networks tab (on the top right), then click **Edit Connections**.
In **Ethernet**, click on **Wired connection 1** (or however the cable connection will be called on your laptop), then click **Edit...**.
Go to **IPv4 settings** and set **Method** to be **Shared to other computers**.

Now go back to **Network Connections** tab, find your **Wi-fi** connection, click **Edit...** go to **IPv4 settings** again and make
sure that the **Method** is set to **Automatic (DHCP)**.

Then connect your RaspberryPi and Laptop with **crossover cable**, and boot the RaspberryPi up. A message **Connected to wired connection 1** might appear briefly on the top right corner.

Finally, open the terminal, type

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

and hope that the terminal asks for a password. If you succeed up to *here*, the most of the work is done. Enter the *RaspberryPi* password (try *raspberry* if you don't know it) and you will get a virtual shell of RaspberryPi.

Checking that Wi-Fi connection has been established one can in the SSH'ed shell type

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

to check for arriving packets. If that succeeds type

```
ping [SomeWebsiteName]
```

to check that DNS works.

If you failed to get "enter password" request, some of the problems can be:

- The **/etc/network/interfaces** files. My files are as follows.

  In Linux Laptop:

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
  ```

  On Raspbian:

  ```
  # Note some lines might not be required

  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  auto eth0
  allow-hotplug eth0
  iface eth0 inet manual

  auto wlan0
  allow-hotplug wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet manual
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

  auto wlan1
  allow-hotplug wlan1
  iface wlan1 inet manual
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
  ```
- **ssh** program is not installed.
- **pi@raspberrypi.local** does not detect the Pi's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop has the Wi-Fi connection and is functioning as an SSH server you can provide web access to the Rasberry Pi by using the laptop as a [SOCKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy. You mentioned you can use Ubuntu or Windows on the laptop. For Linux distributions, such as Ubuntu, [OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH) is commonly used to enable the system to function as an SSH server. You can check if an Ubuntu system is already functioning as an SSH server by running the command `netstat -a` and piping its output into `grep`, searching for "ssh". If it is functioning as an SSH server already, you will see a line or lines indicating it is listening for SSH connections (the default port is 22).

```
$ netstat -a | grep ssh
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
```

If it isn't functioning as an SSH server, run the command `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` from a shell prompt.

If, instead, you are running Microsoft Windows on the laptop, there are a number of SSH server programs that are free for personal use. Some I've used include the following:

[Bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) Personal Edition

[Copssh](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/Copssh501/)

[freeSSHd](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/network/ssh/freeSSHd/)

[PowerShell SSH Server for Windows](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/PSSrvr6/)

[SilverSHielD SSH Server for Windows](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/SilverSHielD/)

Once you have the laptop functioning as an SSH server, you can establish an SSH connection from the laptop to the Rasberry Pi, assuming the Raspberry Pi is running SSH server software, also, then establish a new SSH connection from the Rasbery Pi to the laptop, i.e., for the second connection the laptop is the SSH server. But with the connection back to the laptop, specify that you want the laptop to function as a SOCKS proxy by using an SSH command like `ssh -ND n user@server` where "n" is the port number you wish to use (port 1080 is the port commonly used for SOCKS proxy connections) and "user@server" is a userid for your account on "server", i.e., the laptop in your case, which is allowed to log into the server via SSH ([example](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2006/11/28#ssh-proxy)). You can substitute the IP address for the laptop for `server`, e.g., `jsmith@192.168.3.1`, if your userid on the laptop is jsmith and the IP address for the laptop is 192.168.3.1.

You can then browse the web from the Rasberry Pi using the laptop's connection to the Internet by configuring any browser on the Rasberry Pi to use a SOCKS proxy. The exact steps you will take will depend on the browser you are using, but most browsers will allow you to specify a proxy server to be used as an intermediary server between a system and the Internet, just make sure you select a SOCKS proxy option.

That will only take care of HTTP/HTTPS connections, though. But you can also forward other types of [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) traffic through the laptop. E.g., suppose you need to print from the Rasberry Pi to a printer that is accessible via the laptop on port 9100. You could issue the command below from the Rasberry Pi, assuming that 192.168.3.5 is the printer's address, 192.168.3.1 is your laptop's address and jsmith is your userid on the laptop, and that account on the laptop has permission to log into the laptop via SSH:

`ssh -L 9100:10.0.0.5:9100 jsmith@192.168.3.1`

The command indicates that a local listening port, 9100, should be created on the laptop when you log into the laptop with the SSH connection and that port should be forwarded to port 9100 on the printer which in this example has an IP address of 10.0.0.5 ([example](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2010/05/13/)). You can combine that command with the option to establish a SOCKS proxy, i.e., `ssh -L 9100:10.0.0.5:9100 -ND 1080 jsmith@192.168.3.1`. You could add any additional ports that you need to forward with additional `-L` options. Then, if you needed to print from the Rasberry Pi to the printer via port 9100 on the printer, you could give 192.168.3.1 as the printer's IP address when configuring the Rasberry Pi to communicate with the pritner, even though the printer's actual address is 10.0.0.5. As long as the laptop can communicate with the printer at 10.0.0.5, it can forward connections on port 9100 made to the laptop by the Rasberry Pi to the IP address of the printer.

Alternatively, instead of setting the laptop to function as a SOCKS proxy and forward connections to ports on external systems, you could configure the laptop to function as a router, aka gateway. There are many tutorials available online regarding how to set up an Ubuntu system as a router and also as a [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server, in case you run Ubuntu on the laptop and wish it to provide an IP address to the Rasberry Pi over the crossover cable, e.g., [Ubuntu as a firewall/gateway router](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/ubuntu-as-a-firewallgateway-router/). You can also configure a Windows system to function as a router/gateway.