# Transfer file to Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, powershell, file-transfer, windows-server-2008-r2, scp

In a LAN, I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine; access to server through Remote Desktop is granted both

1) from a LAN host

2) from the internet, thanks to a virtual server configured in the router.

The Windows server has shared folders and it is a Domain Controller.

I need to transfer a file **to** the server in case 1) and 2), from a command-line interface such as PowerShell. If the server ran Linux, for both cases `scp` could be used. But with Windows? Which command, if exists, could provide the same result as `scp`, in a secure connection?

Comment: Is setting up and connecting to a VPN a viable solution?

Comment: @CanadianLuke uhm no, I would like a direct access, just as in `scp`.

Comment: Is this post on SO of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344004/is-there-a-scp-alternative-for-powershell

Comment: [There are many SSH server programs available for Microsoft Windows systems](http://superuser.com/a/1030479/267361), if you could permit SSH connectivity to the system as well as RDP, if you wanted to be able to access the system through scp. [Microsoft's PowerShell team is also working on an SSH server implementation for Windows systems](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/06/03/looking-forward-microsoft-support-for-secure-shell-ssh/), but I don't know when that is expected to be delivered.